# allow current window to scroll to top before changing to another router location with vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like my page to scroll to the top before changing to another tab. I have tried the following code but in vain.

```
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
            <b-navbar-nav class = "ml-5">
                <b-nav-item :active= "$route.matched.some(({ name }) => name === 'tab1')"  class = "navitem" @click= "routehome">tab1</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item :active= "$route.matched.some(({ name }) => name === 'tab2')"  class = "navitem" @click= "routeproject">tab</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item :active= "$route.matched.some(({ name }) => name === 'tab3')"   class = "navitem" @click= "routeexperience">tab3</b-nav-item>
            </b-navbar-nav>
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
```

in script i tried adding this but it doesnt show the animation as the code is running asynchronously.

```
   totab1() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        this.$router.push("/tab1");
    },
    totab2() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        this.$router.push("/tab2");
    },
```

I then tried adding then function but it seems like windows.scroll(0,0) doesnt support then. Is there a way to work around this?

```
    totab3() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0).then(() => {
            this.$router.push("/tab3");
        })
    }
```

Comment: How about a timeout for the the navigation trigger instead of then?

Answer (score 2):

#### Scroll to Top Before Page Change

This can be achieved with Vue-router's [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). Although intended to *guard* routes, they can just as easily be used to call an arbitrary function before a route change.

You could either call this from within a specific component (using [an in component guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)) with

```
beforeRouteLeave() { window.scrollTo(0, 0) }
```

Or, to apply to all routes, apply in you're router.js file, e.g.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
})
```

---

#### Scroll to Top After Page Change

Vue router has a useful [`scrollBehavior`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)  method. In you're case you'd want to return `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` to go to the top and left of the page. So in you're router.js file, add something like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior () {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Alicia , thank you for your answer. However what I would want is for my current page to scroll to the top before changing to another router page. This is just to improve the user experience. I would want the animation of scrolling to end before pushing to another page.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry I misunderstood. Using [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) would be the easiest way to do this, something like: `router.beforeEach(() => { window.scrollTo(0, 0) }`

Comment: Hi @Alicia, thank you again, I'm very new to this and i tried following your code. However, do i have to use the variable to, from and next anywhere as I am getting errors showing that I declare but didnt use. I tried putting them in console.log and run but it still didnt achieve desired result.

Comment: You don't have to use them, no- so you can just remove them from the parameters :)  
If you wanted to say, only run a function for certain routes, that's where the to and from come in handy.